# Google Hangouts client/app which supports group chats

Tags: macos, messages, google, google-hangouts

On OS X Yosemite, I'm using Messages.app to chat with my contacts.

But I can not participate or read group chats from Hangouts within Messages.app, for that I have to use the Gmail/G+ page.

So, anyone knows a client/app for OS X (or even an extension/plugin for Messages.app) which enables me to chat one-on-one and even on group chats?

Comment: Some people on Internet suggests: http://flamingo.im/

But on their AppStore page, they have this warning:
"NOTE: Due to service limitations, Flamingo does not support, (...) chats in Facebook or Google Hangouts/Gtalk (...)"

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Try Jitsi for OSX, it supposedly handles voice for Google Hangouts, but to be honest...

The best way I have found to do this is just to use the following Chrome extension called Hangouts, by Google: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hangouts/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd?utm_source=plus

The thing is that Google Hangouts is no longer a open XMPP/Jabber protocol its sort of a mutant breed of this technology that is becoming more and more closed off providing features across more open traditional Jabber accounts.

The only caveat is that DON'T quit chrome or it dies, my default browser is Firefox fyi. So I run chrome, click the little hangouts bubble, close all the chrome windows and get the cool Hangouts buddy list every time I hover my mouse in the lower right corner of my screen: OSX Yosemite 10.10.4

Comment: I know that extension, for the moment is the one that I use, but IMHO it's not the "right answer" because is a browser extension...

Comment: I just found https://github.com/yakyak/yakyak and would like to update my choice answer to use this program. 

And suggest that if you want to use google voice VOIP and Hangouts VIDEO Chat services you must just use it in it's intended manner by using Chrome and the google hangouts website. This is the new Google, deal with it!